# Why does /([o])\w+/g not match the word to

Tags: regex

I'm learning regex via [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) so that I can be less embarrassingly pathetic when trying to match patterns.

The website provides an explanation for each component of the regex statement, but I'm unable to determine why this expression:

`/([o])\w+/g`

doesn't match any part of the word "to":

[image: regexr]

My understanding is that `[o]` should match the letter `o` and the `\w` switch (or whatever you'd call that... flag? option?) tells it to match words.

I would also benefit from an explanation of why it matches only `o` and the letters after `o` within a word (e.g. `ome` in the word Welcome) rather than the entire word containing the letter `o`).

Finally, the explanation of `+` tells me that it means to "match 1 or more of the preceding token" while toggling this seems to control if only 1 letter after `o` is matched, or all of the letters after `o` in the word is matched. Clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

My apologies for the novice questions.

Comment: `\w` is a word character (usually alpha-numeric with underscores), so `to` doesn't match `/[o]\w+/g` since there are no more word characters after `to`

Comment: @BeyelerStudios thank you, could you explain that a bit more? So, it means to match other character in the word that's been matched, if those characters come after the matched character?

Comment: @Hack-R: `\w` just a shorthand for `[a-zA-z0-9_]`. Just like `\d` is a shorthand for `[0-9]`. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\w` is not a switch, it's a character class for word characters. The exact meaning of `\w` depends on the system, but at the minimum it must match `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. In your example in `"to"` letter `"o"` is followed by a space, which is a non-word character. Since the `+` qualifier requires one or more word characters following `"o"`, the word `"to"` does not match.

Comment: oh okay, thanks that's starting to make sense. So, even though `o` is in the word `to` it's not a match because `\w` requires that the **next** character after the matched character is in a word?

Comment: @Hack-R Yes, exactly.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I will accept this as the solution once the minimum time has passed in 7 minutes.

Comment: @Hack-R: Just to be sure: If you had the expression `oa`, then only sequences would be matched that literally consist of an `o` followed by an `a`. `o\w` only matches sequences that consist of an `o` followed by any of the characters `A` to `Z`, `a` to `z`, `0` to `9` or `_`. So these would match: `oC`, `oc`, `o5`, `o_`, but not `o%`, `o+`, `o a`, etc.

Comment: @FelixKling  ooooo! Yes, that does make it even more clear. You're rocking my world!

Answer (score 2):

Actually `\b\w+\b` would match the word `to` (not in `towards` or in `toe`).
`\b` is a word boundary, while `\w` matches any word character. `\w+` matches at least one word character, unlimited times consecutively.
[RegexOne](http://regexone.com/) is a good starting point to *learn* regular expressions.

Comment: Thank you. I will review that website. If you could add a bit more explanation regarding the statement in the question that would help, though I think @dasblinkenlight has shed some light on it for me.

Comment: Nice, but *why*. The OP doesn't seem to be grasping some aspects of regular expressions and is seeking an understanding here

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: Right you are.

Comment: @Hack-R: `\b` is a word boundary, while `\w` matches any word character. `\w+` matches at least *one* word character, unlimited times consecutively.

Comment: @Jan Ah, ok great. Thank you for your answer; I'll +1 it.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ: I guess this was rather a comment and I'm somewhat tired :)

Comment: @Jan update your answer with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182827/why-does-o-w-g-not-match-the-word-to/36182922?noredirect=1#comment60001387_36182922)

Comment: @Jan - great, +1 as it describes why it doesn't match "to"